# Error 404 Sending JSON Put Method - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: json, api, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, request

I'm developing a mobile application in Xamarin Forms and i have a problem where my Put Method is retorning a 404 status, but if i make the request on Postman it works well...
I can't see the problem...

Here is the **Request**

```
        public async Task<UserHasGamification> AddPointsToUser(UserHasGamification userHasGamification)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.2.202:8080/api/UserGamification");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // Converte seu objeto para formato Json
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userHasGamification);

            // Espera o resultado
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync("userHasGamification", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return userHasGamification;
            }
            return userHasGamification;
        }
```

Here is my **class**

```
    public class UserHasGamification
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }
        public string Points { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is the **error**:

```
{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Sat, 29 Aug 2020 08:46:04 GMT
  Pragma: no-cache
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-Android-Received-Millis: 1598690768707
  X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 404
  X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1598690768679
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 122
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}}
```

The get method work fine...but the PUT Method does not...and i can't quite understand why.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: what is the URL you are using in Postman?

Comment: I'm using "https://localhost:44312/api/UserGamification" which is the url of the API project that i have made

Comment: in C# you're using `http://192.168.2.202:8080/api/UserGamification/userHasGamification`

Comment: @Jason thanks man...my bad! Its working now

Comment: @JoãoGodinho Hi, if have solved this, remember to share the solution in answer when you have time. Then others who meet this will know how to solve that.